# Need help figuring out how to determine biggest and smallest count

Tags: java

I need help trying to figure out how to answer the last 2 parts of this project I was given by coach at the local YMCA. I need to figure out what was the best and worst game of free throws shot by the team. I know the code is kinda clunky and I am sure there is a better way to write various methods to make it smoother, but i am new to Java and keep getting errors. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Final {
public static void main(String[] args) {
//Create input scanner for shooter percentage
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Player's Free Throw Percentage: ");
    int percent = input.nextInt();
    int inCount = 0;

// game and total make/miss counts
    int outCount = 0;
    int Game1 = 0;
    int Game2 = 0;
    int Game3 = 0;
    int Game4 = 0;
    int Game5 = 0;

// Game  random num compared to user input percent and count for game and total
    System.out.println("Game 1:");
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        int randomInt = r.nextInt(100);
    if (percent >= randomInt)
        {
        System.out.print("In" + " ");
        inCount++;
        Game1++;
        }
    if (percent < randomInt)
        {
        System.out.print("Out" + " ");
        outCount++;
        }   
        }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Free throws made: " + Game1 + " out of 10.");

// Game random num compared to user input percent and count for game and total  

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Game 2:");
    Random r2 = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        int randomInt = r2.nextInt(100);
    if (percent >= randomInt)
        {
        System.out.print("In" + " ");
        inCount++;
        Game2++;
        }
    if (percent < randomInt)
        {
        System.out.print("Out" + " ");
        outCount++;
        }   
        }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Free throws made: " + Game2 + " out of 10.");
    System.out.println("");

// Game random num compared to user input percent and count for game and total
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Game 3:");
    Random r3 = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        int randomInt = r3.nextInt(100);
    if (percent >= randomInt)
        {
        System.out.print("In" + " ");
        inCount++;
        Game3++;
        }
    if (percent < randomInt)
        {
        System.out.print("Out" + " ");
        outCount++;
        }   
        }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Free throws made: " + Game3 + " out of 10.");
    System.out.println("");

// Game  random num compared to user input percent and count for game and total
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Game 4:");
    Random r4 = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        int randomInt = r4.nextInt(100);
    if (percent >= randomInt)
        {
        System.out.print("In" + " ");
        inCount++;
        Game4++;
        }
    if (percent < randomInt)
        {
        System.out.print("Out" + " ");
        outCount++;
        }   
        }


    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Free throws made: " + Game4 + " out of 10.");
    System.out.println("");

// Game  random num compared to user input percent and count for game and total
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Game 5:");
    Random r5 = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        int randomInt = r5.nextInt(100);
    if (percent >= randomInt)
        {
        System.out.print("In" + " ");
        inCount++;
        Game5++;
        }
    if (percent < randomInt)
        {
        System.out.print("Out" + " ");
        outCount++;
        }   
        }


    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Free throws made: " + Game5 + " out of 10.");
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Summary:");
    //System.out.println("Best Game Free Throws Made:" + );
    //System.out.println("Worst Game Free Throws Made:");
    System.out.println("Total Free Throws Made: " + (50-outCount) + " " + "out of 50");
    System.out.println("Average Free Throw Percentage:" + (inCount*2) +"%")
}   
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with arrays? Those will help greatly. Even better (for your education) would be to use the ArrayList class.

Comment: Also, your code will be easier to understand if you put in comments indicating what each variable means (aside from trivial ones like loop variables), what each class represents, and what each method is supposed to do. Your main function should generally do *very little*; at most it can handle the IO; all calculations should be happening elsewhere.

Comment: the use of arrays that I have is very limited to pre-defining the array block with integers and then calling them to run methods. I have tried to create a random num generator method in this but when i try to run the boolean and in count with it i cannot get it to produce the correct number of replies.

Comment: I must to bed; others will likely be able to help more. Making a new array is done by `blahblah = new Foo[120]`, but like I said, you'll probably be better off in the long term learning to use ArrayList instead; Java arrays are a bit ... awkward. The language expanded beyond them, and they no longer fit in very well.

Comment: Can someone point me in the direction of how to create a Method to make the arraylist, so i can fill it with randoms and use it repeatedly.

Comment: The full [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) may help. Ignore all the text on top, most of which is irrelevant and some of which is wrong. Just look for the constructors and methods you need. I can't tell what you intend for your code to do, so I can't tell you how, but you certainly should have a `games` ArrayList rather than five variables representing the games.

Comment: I need to  for 5 games have a user input a % for the shooter, then I need the array fro each game to compare to the random 10 shots attempted per game. For each shot made it needs to total at the end of game data. Then after all 5 games have been run against the user %, I need it to tell me the average, lowest game, highest game, and total shots made. I have tried to make a method to make random array but i cant get it to work.

Comment: public class ShotClass {
    //Create random numbers method array
    public  int [] getRandomNumbers(){
        shots = new int [10];
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            shots[i] = r.nextInt(100);
       return shots;
    }

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful? Do you have further questions?

Comment: @dfeuer yes I did, i have redo most of this to create arrays and a single counter to avoid repetition of some of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by writing `randomShot`, a method that produces a random number and returns a boolean value indicating whether a shot was successful.

Next you want to come up with a way to "play a game" and produce the results you need. There are various ways to do this:

- An object-oriented approach would be to use a Game class with a method to play the game (using the randomShot method) and that offers accessor functions to get the results of the game. One way is to build an array of shot results and then calculate what you need from that. There's actually another, somewhat trickier, way that does not build an array of shots.
- A functional way to do this would be to have a class that does nothing but hold the *results* of a game, and accessors to get the details, and to have a game playing method that returns a `GameResult` object. This way allows you to use those same techniques.
- A sort of hybrid approach puts the game playing into the Game constructor, so that each game object only plays one game, and then sits around holding results.

Finally, you want a method that plays five games and presents the results to the user. Again, playing games and building an array with the results is a reasonable way. Again, you can actually avoid building that array by restructuring the code, but again it's likely to be a bit annoying.